# Boto3 way of sending bulk email, with attachments, and download links

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ses

Amazon SES via the Python Boto3 library seems to have a lot of ways to send email. There's `send_raw_email`. There's `send_email`. There's `send_bulk_templated_mail`.

I want to send 3000 emails to my (paying) clients (ie: this is not spam - they pay for my reports). The emails may contain images. They may contain attachments. If the attachments are bigger than 5MB, they will need a download link. Because they are paying clients, I'd like them all to receive the mail more or less at the same time (ie: I don't want this to take long - it has to be as performant as possible).

Which of the above boto3 functions, is the correct one for my use case? I suspect it is `send_bulk_templated_mail`, but I cannot see how to add attachments using this method. Nowhere is it explained in [the documentation for this function](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.send_bulk_templated_email).

Separately, I want to insert unique links for resources such as images, into each mail, so I know which clients have clicked on which images. Can send_bulk_templated_mail do this? If not, what are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, you are expecting too much from Amazon SES.

You would normally use a program (eg campaignmonitor.com) that composes the emails, handles templates, manages the list of recipients, tracks bounces, etc. It could then use Amazon SES as the SMTP server. This would be much easier than trying to do it all yourself.

However, here is the documentation you seek: [Sending personalized email using the Amazon SES API - Amazon Simple Email Service Classic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-personalized-email-api.html)